# Touch screen not working on some screens even after factory reset

Tags: touchscreen

My touchscreen no longer works at all, on MOST screens.

However, there are some screens where the touchscreen consistently works perfectly, so it is extremely difficult to believe that this is an issue with the touchscreen.

The screens where it always works without a problem:

- On the lock screen where I swipe up and then enter in my pattern.
- The menu that appears when the power button is held for a second or two.
- The home screen, where I can swipe left/right and navigate my app list.

My device is the Sony Xperia L3 and I'm using the default launcher.

After factory resetting my phone, the problem persists. I cannot get passed the setup screens. However, once again, the menu that appears when the power button is briefly held works perfectly. I can tap any of the 3 buttons, or tap away, every time.

I dropped my phone 10 months ago and there is a fairly big crack at the bottom right of the screen, and a tiny hole which seems to lead in to the internals. Up until now, it's been working fine. Not only is the touchscreen now acting up but the pixels on the screen are very glitchy.

Any ideas what the problem is and how I can fix this? Again, I'd like to reiterate that for some bizarre reason the touchscreen works fine on certain screens 100% of the time, so I'm hoping that there is some solution without requiring repair or getting new phone.

One possibility why the touchscreen works on some screens and not on others is the following: Perhaps there is a small section of the touchscreen that is constantly being tapped on because of the damage. This would mean on some screens, it thinks I have two fingers on the screen, and thinks I'm trying to zoom and therefore won't let me do anything else. On other screens, it is coded in a way that ignores the second finger.

However, with this possibility in mind, I tried installing the "Partial Screen" app. This allows me to disable the touchscreen on certain sections of the screen. I tried disabling the top half, with the bottom half still broken on the screens where it normally would be. I then tried disabling the bottom half, with the top half still broken on the screens where it normally would be. When I first started the app, it tried to scan areas of the screen with a problem and none were found. So this is making me believe that there is no issue on the touchscreen with areas being constantly tapped on.